# SQLite database file size for storing 8 bit integers

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, filesize

I am trying to store a list of unsigned 8 bit integers in a SQLite database. I am using Python3.4 running on Windows. When I save a list of 1000 numbers, I expect the database file to be around 1KB larger than an empty database which on my machine is around 2KB.

The file size appears to grow to 10KB making it seem like the data is getting stored in an 8 byte number. The table is created with 'INT1' or 'TINYINT' type specifier.

Is there a specific way the data has to be formatted, or is the .db file size not really proportional to the data stored ? In my final application, I would have billions of rows of unsigned integers (and 40 columns)  and I want to estimate the file size of the database.

```
import sqlite3 as sq3 
import numpy as np
conn = sq3.connect('test_db.db')
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE data_3 (int_data TINYINT)''')
list_=np.zeros((1000,1),dtype='uint8')
c.executemany('''INSERT INTO data_3 VALUES(?)''',list_)

conn.commit();
zzzz=c.execute('SELECT * from data_3 ')
list_1=(zzzz.fetchall())
print(len(list_1),list_1[0])
```

Comment: For 1000 small rows, the table and row overhead dominates. Test with 1000000 rows with 40 columns.

Comment: I tried it with 10 million rows and 10 columns (100 M uint) and the database filesize was ~ 300 MB. Isn't that high, a 200 MB overhead for 100 MB of data ?  Is there a document that describes the overhead for each table/data row that is present in SQLite ?

Comment: [The SQLite Database File Format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html). Two bytes per row is quite a low overhead.

Comment: more like 20 bytes per row. 2 bytes per record.

Comment: Each column value has one type byte (see the [record format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format)). I guess many values are 0 or 1, which don't need space for the actual value?